# Label Text Not Updating with correct information gathered from database

Tags: c#, sql-server, t-sql

I am working on a project that involves the restoring of databases using MSSQL.
I run all my queries and open connections using the `System.Data.SqlClient` namespace.

On my main form, as soon as it starts, it will run a query on the database that currently exists (if any does) and will return a value from the database and display it in a label. The code for this query is as follows:

```
private void getSNumber() {
     SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(getConnectionString());
        string SNumSQL = @"USE MAINDB  
                        SELECT SNumber FROM Information";
        SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand(SNumSQL, conn);

        conn.Open();

        using (SqlDataReader SNumber = cmd2.ExecuteReader())
        {
            if (SNumber.HasRows)
            {
                while (SNumber.Read())
                {
                    lblSNum.Text = SNumber.GetString(0);
                }
            }
        }
     conn.Close();
     conn.Close();
}
```

This method runs on a timer every 10 seconds and updates just fine.
The problem arises when I restore a database. Restoring a database opens a new form that has all the controls for the actual process. When the "Restore" dialog is opened, the timer is stopped. Once the database is restored and the main form is shown once again, the timer starts up again and retrieves the information but does not display the number correctly in the label. Below is a screenshot of this explanation (sensitive information omitted):

[image]

"**6562**" is the value that should have been shown but does not update the label itself.

I have tried adding a `this.Refresh();` to the timer and have tried clearing any connections to the database after the restore and have double checked to make sure all my connections are closed and disposed of after performing all tasks on the database.

The field will only update if I completely stop the application all together and re-run it so I am wondering if there is something with my connection to the database that does not refresh once a new database has been restored.

Comment: What consist the `Restore db` process? If your query is working ok, Then the problem is somewhere else

Comment: The restore process is a very simple query that runs a "RESTORE DATABASE MAINDB FROM DISK='etc etc etc'

Comment: I cant see where the error is, try creating two button to remove the timer situation. One button `A` to display label and another `B`  for the Restore..  Then Click `A - B - A`

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza I added a button that simply calls getSNumber() and that works fine... I am just not sure why that doesnt work in the timer.

Comment: That is good at least we know Label and Restore are working. Are you sure the timer restart after the `RESTORE`?

Comment: Yes, after the restore is completed and the main form shows once again.. I let it run and the breakpoint catches when the timer ticks.

Comment: why `lblSNum.Text  = ` is inside a  `While loop` ??

Comment: The `SqlDataReader` will only ever loop once. So it updates it one time and stops.

Comment: I figured out that when I click the button to restore, it stops the Timer. When the restore form is closed, its supposed to restart it but it isnt.

Comment: Well I told you to check that :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing the `Timer.Stop();` statement when the restore dialog appears solved the problem. It is unnecessary as when the restore form appears, the main form stops the timer when it is closed and will restart properly when shown again.